# Troubleshooting SSH across networks when ICMP is not enabled

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have 5 Debian Linux servers at my main work, and a few at some of our off-site locations, and one personal one at home. I can SSH with PuTTY from Work to any of the 5 in the same building, and some of the off sites, plus my home. One site, I cannot access from work.

I have the correct IP address and port number, and the remote server is configured correctly (port forwarding, firewall allowing my networks, etc). I am on a semi-restrictive network, and nothing seems to have changed, except for accessing this remote server.

When I add the `-vvv` for "very verbose output" from a work server, I just see `Connection timed out`. If I SSH home, then SSH from there to this particular server, I can log in, and no issues connecting.

My ISP at work blocks ICMP requests - ping, traceroute, et al are disabled. The remote server I am trying to connect to does not have any Internet-facing services on it, except for my SSH so I can administer it from here.

**What can I look for as to a reason why it can be connected from home, but not from my work?** I am the tech for this building, so I have root access to these servers, but I have no access to the ISP (who claims that nothing has changed).

Comment: do you have the same ISP at home as you do at work? And if you try to access the server from another place with the same and another place with a different ISP, what's the result?

Comment: I have the same ISP as the off-site server, but the work ISP is a government organization.

Comment: Have you looked into the possibility that they're blocking an IP range, that the server happens to falls into?

Comment: They better not have.. I can connect from the remote server to my work servers, and they have only a white list

Comment: I suppose a path MTU problem, coupled with a PMTU Discovery black hole caused by your ISP's ICMP blocking, could cause this. Try cranking your MTU down to 1300 on your SSH client machine and the server in question and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: TCP traceroute utilities can be useful for this kind of troubleshooting... it uses a TCP packet with increasing TTL to replicate the ICMP/UDP function.

Comment: @cpt_fink Do you have any suggestions of a tool to use?

Comment: For Linux, traceroute looks like it has a TCP option, but I've never used it. For Windows there's several options listed here http://serverfault.com/questions/49235/traceroute-tcp-equivalent-for-windows

Comment: @cpt_fink I get a response, saying it's filtered: `2222/tcp filtered unknown`